# Display Only Mapkit Annotations From Firebase Created Within The Last Hour

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mapkit

I am currently able to pull down all of my annotations from Firebase Firestore and display them with no problem.  In my snapshot listener I would like to be able to only display annotations created within the last hour.  I've included my code below that isn't working and is still returning all annotations in my Firestore.

`let hourAgo = Date().addingTimeInterval(-3600)`

````
        db.collection("pins").addSnapshotListener { QuerySnapshot, Error in
            guard let documents = QuerySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            let annotation = documents.map { QueryDocumentSnapshot -> Pin in
                let data = QueryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let latitude = data["latitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                let longitude = data["longitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                let eventTitle = data["eventTitle"] as? String ?? ""
                let eventSubtitle = data["eventSubtitle"] as? String ?? ""
                let lastUpdated = data["lastUpdated"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp.init()
                let pinDate = lastUpdated.dateValue()
                
                let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                if pinDate >= self.hourAgo {
                    self.displayPins(coordinate: coordinate, eventSubtitle: eventSubtitle, eventTitle: eventTitle)
                }else{
                    return Pin(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, eventTitle: eventTitle, eventSubtitle: eventSubtitle)
                }
                //print(annotation)
                return Pin(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, eventTitle: eventTitle, eventSubtitle: eventSubtitle)
            }
            
        }
    }
    func displayPins(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, eventSubtitle: String, eventTitle: String) {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        annotation.title = eventTitle
        annotation.subtitle = eventSubtitle
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }```
````

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see what `data["lastUpdated"]` or `lastUpdated` is? Also, your current `map` function is a strange use of `map`, since you're not updating a collection. In fact, you're probably getting a compiler warning about it. You aren't doing anything with the `Pin`s that you're returning (unless there's more code that you aren't showing).

Comment: This is my first app.  I honestly don't quite know how I got to that point, but it did what it it to do until I wanted to filter what was displayed and I took the "It maybe ugly, but it works" approach.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I think I can help you with both Firestore and MapKit annotations